# Limit form responses to once per person....without login?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am designing a test, I want people to only respond to test once, but without making them log in via Google. Is there any way I can retrieve IP addresses and/or use a cookie to limit their responses?

Comment: fyi, not a great plan either way. cookies are easy to clear, and IP addresses easy to change.

Comment: its alright, if someone specifically changes ip address for that let it be. But if I choose setlimitoneperuser in google scripts it will always limit the number of people answering the test.

Answer (score 0):

no, nonexof your wishes are possible currently with Google forms. in fact forms do not support running any code during form fill.

your only options are to either host the google form in your own domain and add custom javascript (not officially supported but google it) or to somehow filter out those responses later (onFormSubmit and such based on other unique data in form fields)

Comment: how can I see who submitted twice?

Comment: somehow inferred from fields. maybe you ask the user their email as a question. cheatable kf course. even ips can be faked but harder to cheat for an average user

Comment: isa there any way I can track viewers navigation through pages?

Comment: no but look at my answer regarding hosting it in your own page